# Execute of job failed. See the history log for details

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am learning SQL Server administration and setting up log shipping for the first time. SERVER1 is primary database and SERVER2 is secondary database. I was able to setup log shipping successfully from SERVER1 and database has been created on SERVER2, however, when i am trying to manually run the Job it is giving me below error:
[image]

After checking the logs in text file, i noticed that it is giving me this error:
[image]

Initially, SERVER2 was named as SERVER, i thought this might have been the problem, so i rename the server using sproc `sp_addserver` and `sp_dropserver`. However, it did not do the trick. Then i noticed that under regedit Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\120\machines, name was still SERVER so changed it from there to SERVER2 and restarted the machine. Tried running the job manually again it still gave me the same error. Turned off the firewall of SERVER1 completely, issue still persists. Also, under the shared folder on SERVER2, db backup file is not generated. I am wondering now what is this SERVER exactly here in log referring to. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated!!

Comment: Are you able to connect SERVER1 from SERVER2?